# PHP Ping server monitor code optimisation

Tags: php, html

I have picked up a PHP ping tool and with help from another member here I have managed to get it to display everything I need correctly. The problem I'm having is this has to ping 115 different IP Addresses and some times gets the "Fatal Error maximum execution time of 30 seconds"

I have copied the code below and have only added 1 host and 1 service as to save space but there is normally 115 hosts and 115 services.

```
$host1[1] = "8.8.8.8";//These addresses are generic for security reasons.
$host1[2] = "8.8.8.8";
$host1[3] = "8.8.8.8";

$services1[1] = "site 1";//These site names are generic for security reasons.
$services1[2] = "site 2";
$services1[3] = "site 3";

    $counter = "";
        $has_down = false;   // flag, no sites are down yet
        foreach ($host1 as $value1) 
        {
          $counter = $counter + 1;
          echo "<tr>"; 
          echo '<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000"></body>';       
          //check target IP or domain
          $pingreply = exec("ping -n $count $value1");
          if ( substr($pingreply, -2) == 'ms')
            {

            }
          else 
            {
                echo "<p><font size='6'><center><strong><div class='alert alert-danger'>" . $services1[$counter] . " - No Reply</div></strong></center></font></p>";
                // site down, set flag
                $has_down = true;
            }
        }

        // flag still false, all sites work
        if (!$has_down) {
            echo "<p><font size='6'><center><strong><div class='alert alert-success'>All sites responding to pings</div></strong></center></font></p>";
        }
```

Where there is $host1 and $services1 I have 115 of these but I have only put 3 on the code here so it doesn't take up loads of space on the question.

Is there any way I can improve this as it is taking a long time to load the page and it is sometimes getting a fatal error if it takes to long.

Also I believe it is only sending 1 ping per $host but i'm wondering if I can get this to send 4 ping packets to site and if it gets an average ping response then the site is up, as we have some sites on ADSL Lines which often drop packets when pinging so when the site refreshes it says they are down but they have only dropped 1 ping.

Can we optimise this and increase the amount of pings to site?

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: You run this from browser, right? I don't want to sound like an a-hole, but the whole premise of this tool is wrong. If you want to have a tool that tells you whether site is alive, you don't do it by synchronously pinging 115 addresses. Also, you'll receive so many false positives because if a destination is unreachable for you, it doesn't mean it's unreachable for someone else. Are those sites you're pinging yours or not?

Comment: Some servers blocking ping requests (false positives) so many of them tells you they're down, but they are accessable for normal users.

Comment: Hi guys, all the sites(By sites i mean physical buildings im pinging the primary router at the building) are accessable on our MPLS and all respond to pings from the server the reason why some go down and up is because then are on ADSL Lines which drop pings often.

Comment: Iv managed to change the ping count to 2 but this makes the page take around 3 minutes to load so iv had to put a php timeout limit increaser im just wondering how to make the page not take 3 minutes to load. I have the page on a 5 minute reload javascript and its displayed on 2 TV monitors on our service desk. Any way to optimise this so it loads quicker so maybe i can increase the count.

Comment: You are using **synchronous** pinging script **from browser**. It cannot WORK properly. The way this is done is by placing a service at premises which REPORTS every X minutes that it's alive. The place it reports at is available to you via HTTP or some other way. Instead of asking whether your physical location is alive by pinging it, you simply check when it last reported it's alive. That's the **proper way**. Not by creating a ping script that you run in browser. Short answer - no, it's not possible to make it faster. You're free to continue to solve your problem the hacky way though. GL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply N.B How would i be able to get a router on a site tell me its alive and then report it via HTML? Are you able to assist with that?

Comment: I never said that it reports with HTML... I can understand you've got a job to do, and I can also understand you need a solution *fast*. This browser script, as you noticed, is not a proper solution. Routers usually, depending on the make, have some flavor of Linux on them. That gives you all the tools you can ever need to set up a simple service that sends some data somewhere (to an IP). I've given you a hint, and there's a million companies out there who offer managed services that can do this for you. It shouldn't even cost too much to outsource this to someone who dealt with it before.

Comment: Or, you can still run that silly browser script and wonder why it times out every time your router changes IP.

Comment: Im just trying to help out our service desk analysts without spending any money, Thanks for your replies N.B but they are not helping me in the situation.

Comment: Your company is paying **YOU** to deal with a problem and I'm willing to bet that you spend well over 8 hours on this. So why wouldn't they have you do your day-to-day job and pay someone else to sort this problem quickly? Had you created a script via CLI that does this using nonblocking sockets, then this becomes a whole different thing. But, you went with a browser script. I suggested a solution, it's up to you and your company whether you want to waste money on unproductive solution. This script won't solve your problems, and as much as you view me as some sort of "enemy" - I tried to help

Comment: I dont see you as some sort of "enemy" but your comments are not helping with this question/code My company is not paying me specificly to do this, im doing this to help my fellow analysts. There is not management want for the application. Im also doing this project out of hours. Just trying to help my fellow analysts with what basic knowledge and skills i have. I do thank you for your comments but what you have suggest is not possible for me and if you think its not possible for this php script to work then so be it. Just hoping someone would any ideas to help thats all.

Comment: Here's a different suggestion - instead of having 1 script that pings 115 servers, why don't you create a web app where someone can see these 115 servers and press a button to ping a specific one? Split the 115 pings into 115 http requests. That way each request will deal with 1 server only, and if it times out - you can deduce that the server is unavailable. it's an interesting off-hours project and if you make 1 http request ping 1 server, you've made your life easier and you let the web server worry about spawning sufficient processes to satisfy your queries (that's how it should be).

Comment: Good Idea N.B but this webpage sits on 2  50" TV's on our service desk so while the analysts are on the phones they can look up and see in the location the user is call from is down or up. Also this is for a proactive response to a location having no network so we can quickly get in contact with someone at the site to start troubleshooting the network. i need it to tell us without prompting it is a site is up or down. it currently refreshes the site every 5 minutes so we are only 5 minutes behind a site going down.

Comment: I was thinking though, Would running 115 different scripts on the page be better than 115 hosts in 1 script or does it make no difference?